# I need some help to understand this combination of methods (reduce, concat and map)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am studying ES6 and I am strugling with this line of code. I know I am losing something here and I just can't understand what is really happening.

The code:

```
const powerset = arr => 
                arr.reduce((a, v) => 
                    a.concat(a.map(r => 
                        [v].concat(r))), [[]]);

console.log(powerset([1, 2, 3]));
```

The output:

```
[[], [1], [2], [2, 1], [3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

What do I see here?

the first `concat` will concatenate inside the 'primary array' the return of each `map`, and this one will concatenate the value of `r` with the value of `v`, and I believe that `r` is equal to `a`.

Based on that what I understand is that (I know I am wrong, but I don't know why) it should work like this:

In the first 'level' `a` is an empty array and `v` is equal to 1, so the first value should be `[1]` and not `[]`, since `r` is being concatenate with `v`; in the second 'level' `a` is equal to 1 and `v` to 2, what would return `[2, 1]` and in the third 'level' the return would be `[3, 2, 1]` since `v` is equal to 3 and `a` to `[2, 1]`.

As I said before, I know I am wrong but I just can't see what I am losing here. I made my research, as well as a lot of experiments, but I didn't get it.

How is this code really working?

Comment: FWIW, even someone who's rather experienced has to squint a lot to figure that out…

Comment: Break it into smaller parts and figure out what exactly is being passed to each nested function, and what that function in turn produces.

Comment: Try putting `console.log("adding", v, "to", JSON.stringify(a))` in the `reduce` callback, that should get you going

Comment: @symlink I have been doing this for hours and I understood each part, but not all them together.

Comment: Two things where you're wrong: `a` is never an empty arrray (if it was it wouldn't work), it's starting with `[[]]`. The `r` are the *elements* of `a`, and the first `r` is indeed an empty array.

Comment: @Bergi when I call it an empty array I am referring exactly to the initial value. Sorry for the confusion,

Comment: @Bergi and yes, the first `r` is an empty array, but `v` is equal to 1, that is the point, I didn't understand why the first output is `[]` and not `[1]`, since `r` and `v` are being concatenated

Comment: Because you never replace the first index of the initial value [[]]. concat just joins arrays together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first fix that formatting a bit:

```
arr.reduce(
  (a, v) => a.concat(a.map(r => [v].concat(r))),
  [[]]
)
```

So, `reduce` takes `[[]]` as the starting value, and the callback returns this list concatenated with something else. So far so good, makes sense that the return value is `[[], ...]` then, it's the starting value with additional values appended.

With three values being passed into `powerset`, there will be three iterations of this `reduce` process.

Now, what is being concatenated to that list each turn?

```
a.map(r => [v].concat(r))
```

`a` is that list that it starts with and that will be returned, `v` is the current value from `arr`, the list that was passed into `powerset` to begin with. `r` is each value currently in `a`.

So, on the first iteration, `a` is `[[]]`, so `r` will be `[]` once, and `v` is `1`:

```
  [[]].map(_ => [1].concat([]))
→ [[]].map(_ => [1])  // [1].concat([]) is [1]
→ [[1]]
```

So this first `map` operation returns `[[1]]`:

```
  (a, _) => a.concat([[1]])
→ (_, _) => [[], [1]]
```

So, you're indeed seeing the beginning of the output here. On the next iteration, `a` is `[[], [1]]` and `v` is `2`.

```
  a        .map(r => [v].concat(r))
→ [[], [1]].map(r => [2].concat(r))  // two mappings here:
  → []  → [2].concat([])             // [2]
  → [1] → [2].concat([1])            // [2, 1]
→ [[2], [2, 1]]
```

So:

```
  (a, _) => a.concat([[2], [2, 1]])
→ (_, _) => [[], [1], [2], [2, 1]]
```

And you can figure out the third iteration yourself.

Comment: It is very clear now. Thank you very much. It was driving me crazy lol. But seeing your explanation I believe I get what I was losing now. In fact it was two things, I wasn't considering the empty array in the first index of `a` nor the entire array when applying `map`, just the current value. But now it is all clear. Thank you again.